# How do you set a title so that every row in a table has the title already typed in when you add a new row?

Tags: cocoa, core-data

I am using a Core-Data app, i am looking to set a pre-defined title/word so that every new row that is created already has that title/word typed in.
For example the word could be 'New Task' and so when the user adds a new row it would already say 'New Task', how would you do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [this article](http://www.cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000085.php).  It tells you how to set default values for attributes (under the Configure the Attribute heading)